# What makes DbDataProvider not RESTful?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, rest

I have heard a few people make the comment that the default controller/provider for Entity Framework data in the new ASP.NET WebAPI (DbDataController) is not, strictly speaking, a REST based service, but more like an RPC-style service. I understand that the WebAPI framework allows you to make any kind of HTTP service, REST or otherwise, but can someone explain to me specifically what it is about the service exposed by a DbDataController that makes it not a true REST service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REST architectural style describes the following six constraints applied to the architecture, while leaving the implementation of the individual components free to design:

**Client–server**

> A uniform interface separates clients from servers. This separation of
>   concerns means that, for example, clients are not concerned with data
>   storage, which remains internal to each server, so that the
>   portability of client code is improved. Servers are not concerned with
>   the user interface or user state, so that servers can be simpler and
>   more scalable. Servers and clients may also be replaced and developed
>   independently, as long as the interface between them is not altered.

**Stateless**

> The client–server communication is further constrained by no client
>   context being stored on the server between requests. Each request from
>   any client contains all of the information necessary to service the
>   request, and any session state is held in the client. The server can
>   be stateful; this constraint merely requires that server-side state be
>   addressable by URL as a resource. This not only makes servers more
>   visible for monitoring, but also makes them more reliable in the face
>   of partial network failures as well as further enhancing their
>   scalability.

**Cacheable**

> As on the World Wide Web, clients can cache responses. Responses must
>   therefore, implicitly or explicitly, define themselves as cacheable,
>   or not, to prevent clients reusing stale or inappropriate data in
>   response to further requests. Well-managed caching partially or
>   completely eliminates some client–server interactions, further
>   improving scalability and performance.

**Layered system**

> A client cannot ordinarily tell whether it is connected directly to
>   the end server, or to an intermediary along the way. Intermediary
>   servers may improve system scalability by enabling load-balancing and
>   by providing shared caches. They may also enforce security policies.

**Code on demand (optional)**

> Servers are able temporarily to extend or customize the functionality
>   of a client by the transfer of executable code. Examples of this may
>   include compiled components such as Java applets and client-side
>   scripts such as JavaScript.

**Uniform interface**

> The uniform interface between clients and servers, discussed below,
>   simplifies and decouples the architecture, which enables each part to
>   evolve independently. The four guiding principles of this interface
>   are detailed below.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Constraints

"The only optional constraint of REST architecture is code on demand. If a service violates any other constraint, it cannot strictly be considered RESTful. DbDataController class exposes Entity Framework models as HTTP services. These services have a great feature overlap with WCF Data Services, such as CRUD support, metadata and request batching. They even partially mimic OData's query string format.But these services follow the RPC style they're not RESTful and they don't use OData." A qoute from this site:

[WCF Data Services and ASP.NET Web API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Constraints)

Comment: While helpful, this answer doesn't point to which constraint is violated by DbDataController, or specifically why that constraint is violated. Also, what makes it an RPC-style service?

Comment: An RPC is initiated by the client, which sends a request message to a known remote server to execute a specified procedure with supplied parameters. The remote server sends a response to the client, and the application continues its process, in the same way the DBDataControl provides a fast and efficient way to retrieve and edit data from any relational database. So we can say it is like a RPC style service.

Comment: By that definition, ALL REST services could also be called RPC services, if the server end implemented each kind of REST request with a corresponding procedure call. Are there any substantive differences between what you would call a "pure" REST API and what DbDataController does, or am I not understanding this RPC concept fully?